# Single page application approach with rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, single-page-application

How do you do a single page application in rails that still has linkable routes?

For example:
I could just listen to events like clicks on my menu and do ajax calls like this to replace the pages content.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/home/posts",
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
      $("#postFeed").append(html);
    }
});
```

But that still only gives me one route `/home`.
Is it possible to manage rails to listen to routes like `/home#posts`, `/home#contact`, `home#about` etc.

Answer (score 2):

The # part of the url actually never even makes it to the server. It's just for the browser's reference. So, no, you can't make rails or any other server-side framework listen to hash-based routes.

However, you can use these new MV* javascript frameworks like Ember and AngularJS to do stuff with hash routes, so look into them. I've barely used them, but for a single page app, they'll server you much better than jQuery anyway.

Comment: Ok. So its impossible to do this within the framework of Rails. If i use these javscripts frameworks like Angular Backbone etc i need to let them handle the routing. Why should i even bother using Rails then? Rails tend to be a framework best used to create a backend/API. Am i wrong? @joshua.paling

Comment: Yes, rails is best for a backend / API. If you're using a frontend framework like Angular or Ember, you'll most likely also need a backend framework to provide an API for your frontend framework to communicate with. Rails will be good for this.

Answer (score 0):

A good approach would be to use [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

This allows you, on modern browsers, to change url while still staying on the same page (and thus, on the same javascript execution environment).

The idea is to write your app as a classic multipage website, then handle javascript routing using `pushState` and the `popstate` event.

This has major advantages :

- your full website has still unique urls user can access directly
- it is thus indexable by search engines
- older browsers user just follow link normally, with full page refresh, so it degrades gracefully

Handling history is a deep topic with lot of implications, so you should read documentation about it (even if you use helper javascript frameworks handling it for you), but here is the basics :

```
$( 'a' ).click( function( event ){
  // check if pushState is supported
  if ( window.history && window.history.pushState ){
    var $link = $( this );
    event.preventDefault();

    // change url
    history.pushState( {}, '', $link.attr( 'href' ) );

    // call your page change handler, which typically
    // request content, add it in page and show it
    // with animation - you're responsible of implementing
    // this `change_page` method
    change_page( $link.attr( 'href' ) );
  }
});

// triggered when user press the back button
// *and* on page load
$(window).on( 'popstate', function(){
  // does the page change
  change_page( window.location.href );
});
```

Comment: This was very interesting. I never used pushState before. Thank you for sharing a very nice approach!